# Update Manager crashes, says it needs 3.2.0.58.69 but linux-image-generic on system is 3.2.0.59.70

Tags: updates, update-manager, dependencies

Recently Update Manager ceased working. Ubuntu Software Centre, when I enter it instead, offers to repair, then fails and offers to repair again, and so on.

This is the key sentence I keep getting and am sick of seeing:

```
linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.58.69); however: Version of linux-image-generic on system is 3.2.0.59.70.
```

It makes no sense to me. Why would linux need an earlier version than the one installed to update itself?

I am not certain, but it may be that this problem started after attempting to install Google Chrome.

**When I checked with Synaptic PM**, having tried some of the suggested apt commands at the unmet dependencies thread to no avail, **it identified linux-generic as broken**, tried to update to 3.2.0.60.71, but then failed again, saying it needed the earlier version (which synaptic says is installed).But that 3.2.0.60.71 is installed instead!

So, it says it needs to upgrade, but then acts like it already has. I have not seen anyone else with precisely (no pun intended) this problem on these forums, though someone else unknown has saved virtually the same system response on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/vqUHZT53).

Comment: try this command `sudo apt-get clean` `sudo apt-get autoclean` and then try `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`

Comment: I cannot post the output. It will not let me paste it above in the original question, or here. Instead, I've put it here: http://pastebin.com/hJ4p9Yyf I don't know what else to do, sorry. This is the first question I've ever had to ask on a Linux help site. Every other Ubuntu problem I've ever had I've been able to solve eventually by searching and reading and experimenting.

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/142808/184942)?

Comment: I found this link looking for another way to "show versions", could it have the answer? It sounds very similar. http://askubuntu.com/questions/261230/unmet-dependencies-linux-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that `linux-generic` and other packages depending on it, like `linux-image-generic` need to be of same version.But on your system, They both are of different version.There are many reasons for this, which I won't go in details of.

As `linux-generic` is not an **essential** package, you can reinstall it to fix the system.

To do this, run the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

> **NOTE:-** It is a good idea to run `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoclean` occasionally.This considerably decreases the chances of future dependency problems.

Comment: Thank you again. I have ticked your answer. Let me know how to vote your reputation higher, if that;s the right term, as clicking on the votes tab didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: NO no no no, don't do that.It will cause both of ours accounts to be suspended.

Comment: OK, no problems. I'll just have to learn how the rules work here.

Comment: Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), it is useful.Also read [what behavior is expected from users](http://askubuntu.com/help/behavior) and [what is bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/bounty).

Comment: OK, but I don't think I even gave you one "vote", as I could not find where to do it. I just found out what you had received in the past from others. All I could manage was the green-edged tick above. And, while I would have been happy to give the bounty thing to you, I have no reputation to do it with.

Comment: @user258425 you need minimum 15 rep to upvote and even more to downvote.Also bounty requires 75 rep to start offering.accepting is more than enough.